# How to sort two arrays based on ratio in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, interface

I'd like to sort 2 arrays based on the ratios of their matching indices.   So based on the ratio of a[x]/b[x], a[] and b[] are sorted accordingly.  Here is the basic structure:

```
double[] a = {60.0, 100.0, 120.0};
double[] b = {20.0, 50.0, 30.0};

r0 = a[0]/b[0]
r1 = a[1]/b[1]
r2 = a[2]/b[2]
...
```

The Java code I'm working on doesn't work.  Could someone give me some help?

```
Arrays.sort(ratio, new Comparator<double[]>() {
    @Override
    public double compare(double[] a, double[] b) {
        double r1 = (double)a[i]/b[i];
        double r2 = (double)a[i+1]/b[i+1];
        return r1 > r2;
    }

});
```

Comment: I don't understand your intention, but based on what you wrote, the error seems to be `r1 = (double) a/b`. You tried dividing two arrays. JVM doesn't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
double[] a = new double[10];
double[] b = new double[10];
// fill data to a and b.
int[] indexes = IntStream.range(0, a.length)
    .boxed()
    .sorted((i, j) -> Double.compare(a[i] / b[i], a[j] / b[j]))
    .mapToInt(i -> i)
    .toArray();
double[] sortedA = IntStream.of(indexes)
    .mapToDouble(i -> a[i])
    .toArray();
double[] sortedB = IntStream.of(indexes)
    .mapToDouble(i -> b[i])
    .toArray();
```

If you do not use Java8.

```
double[] a = new double[10];
double[] b = new double[10];
// fill data
int length = a.length;
Integer[] indexes = new Integer[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    indexes[i] = i;
Arrays.sort(indexes, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return Double.compare(a[o1] / b[o1], a[o2] / b[o2]);
    }
});
double[] sortedA = new double[length];
double[] sortedB = new double[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    sortedA[i] = a[indexes[i]];
    sortedB[i] = b[indexes[i]];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.  But I got compiled at:                    Arrays.sort(indexes, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return Double.compare(a[o1] / b[o1], a[o2] / b[o2]);
    }  
});

Comment: error: no suitable method found for sort(Double[],<anonymous Comparator<Integer>>)
    Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Integer>() {
          ^
    method Arrays.<T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
        inferred: Double
        upper bound(s): Integer,Object)

Comment: con't of the error msg: method Arrays.<T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>)

Comment: Did you declare `Integer[] indexes`?

Comment: @ saka2019 , yes.  I think I got it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a `Pair` like this:

```
static class Pair {
    double a;
    double b;
    Pair(double a, double b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

and put arrays into an array of pairs. Then it's easy to sort them:

```
Pair[] p = new Pair[a.length];
for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
    p[i] = new Pair(a[i], b[i]);

Arrays.sort(p, (p1, p2) -> Double.compare(p1.a/p1.b, p2.a/p2.b));
```

Of course, the results are in the new array. You can loop and put them back to `a` and `b` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let us see an example first:

Question: Which is the larger among the two? `8/6` or `9/7`?

Answer: An easy way is to do the following for any two numbers of the form `a/b` and `c/d`. Find `a*d` and `b*c`. If `a*d` is bigger then `a/b` is greater than `c/d`, otherwise `c/d` is greater.

According to the example: `8*7=56` `>` `9*6=54`, hence `8/6` is greater than `9/7`.

So, use the above logic in the **Comparator**.